# detect enter key in JTextField and do something in actionperformed

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

As i have seen many answers are too obscure for a entry level student like me.

i am following the steps by first `addActionListner(this)` to my `JTextField`.

what i am trying to do next and confuses the most is under:

```
public void actionperformed(Actionevent ae){
     if(ae.getSource() == "Enter pressed")
         {
          outArea.setText(result);
         }
}
```

which does not work because i feel like the code `ae.getSource() == "Enter presses"` is not working correctly and even i replaced the action i took under actionPerformed by a simple print line command like System.out.println("working"), it won't execute.

here is what i do if a button is pressed.

```
    public void actionperformed(Actionevent ae){
     if(ae.getSource() == "JButton")
         {
          System.out.println("JButton was pushed");
         }
}
```

no matter how, lets say i have a GUI with a piece of given code like these:

```
  public static void main(string[] args){
 new myProg();
 } 
  public myProg(){
  ....
  buildTheGUI();
  ...}

           }
//GUI Objects
 ...
JTextField input = new JTextField(10);
 ...

//method building the GUI

public void buildTheGUI(){
...
input.addActionListner(this);
...

//a method called actionPerformed
public void actionperformed(Actionevent ae){
}
```

i am now trying to detect the enter key by actionListner not by any other method because it's given.

Comment: what is the possible value of `ae.getSource()`? you **don't** compare `string` using `==`. use `.equals()` instead

Comment: To which `Component` do you add the ActionListener? Can you show us more Code? In your If-Statement you have to check if the Button is clicked with `.equals()` not `==`.

Comment: that's what confuses me coz i am comparing using "==" when a button is pressed, like ae.getSource()=="JButton"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `actionPerformed` is triggerd by an action event, typically on most systems, this is triggered by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (with context to the `JTextField`)...so you don't need to check for it.

Secondly, the `source` of the `ActionEvent` is typically the control that triggered it, that would be the `JTextField` in this case.

Thirdly, `String` comparison in Java is done via the `String#equals` method...

```
 if ("Enter presses".equals(someOtherString)) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actionPerformed method for the Button is wrong, try better this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        System.out.println("This button was pushed: " + button.getText());
    }
}
```

And your for KeyListener try this to learn how it works:

```
@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
        System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
    }
```

Dont forget to let your class implement `ActionListener` and `KeyListener`.

Comment: the second part would justify a downvote ;-) Didn't because the first seems to pinpoint the OP's problem (though hard to tell what exactly that is)

Comment: You should never use a key listener on a text component. You can't guarantee the order in which listeners are notified and it's possible that on some systems of implementations your listener will never be notified. keyListener also doesn't take to account the case when the user pastes content into the field. ActionListener will take care of the the case of the use repressing enter, that's what it's therefore...you also need to consider that the enter may not always be the "action" key on all systems. For example, the Metal look and feel allows a user to use space for buttons...